# Distributed Trunking With core and Access Swtiches?

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, network-core, trunk

Is it possible to set up a Distributed Trunk with 2 Core an 1 Acces Switch on HP 5406zl?
I know that you can connect two switches with an interswitchconnect port. That would be the 2 core switches. Now you can set up a Distributed trunk, e.g. you want to plug in a server with one cabel per switch.

First Question: will the traffic run over one cabel until it's link is down or are the switches performing kind of load balancing?

Second Question: can i connect a Acces Switch with the same method?

See Graph below
[image: Graph_Switch]

Thanks in Advance, Sorry for Mistakes :P

Greeting From Germany, Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HP Switches support distributed trunking, so yes you can connect a switch to the trunk.  The trunk is a single logical link, so yes the traffic is load balanced based on some combination of source and destination mac addresses.